# Fixed Sum of Random Variables

Tags: probability

I got the following from a textbook and I'm not quite sure how some of the steps are derived.

Consider a collection of $n$ random variables, $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ and let their sum be denoted by S, where

$S = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$

The variance of the random variable $S$ is as follows:

$Var[S] = E[(S - E[S])^2]$
                          $=E[S^2] - E[S]^2$
                          $=E[(X_1+X_2+...+X_n)^2] - (E[X_1] + E[X_2]+...+E[X_n])^2$

The following two lines are where I get confused:

$=\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i^2] + 2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j>i}^n E[X_iX_j] - (E[X_1] + E[X_2] + ... + E[X_n])^2$
                          $=\sum_{i=1}^n (E[X_i^2] - E[X_i]^2) + 2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j>i}^n (E[X_iX_j] - E[X_i]E[X_j])$

I understand how to from here to the conclusion, which is

$=\sum_{i=1}^n Var[X_i] + 2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j>i}^n Cov[X_i, X_j]$

Could someone help me with the two intermediate steps?

Comment: It would be simpler if you worked with $Cov$ from the beginning. If you then verify separately that $Cov$ is bi-linear and $Cov(X,X)=Var(X)$, you'll get your result more easily.

Comment: The first line in question results from applying the [Multinomial Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)

Comment: Found a better proof with explanations here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31177/does-the-variance-of-a-sum-equal-the-sum-of-the-variances)